# Format component attributes next line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code

Is there any way we can set the VS code formatter to format components in Angular 2+ templates to wrap attributes in a new line. I want it to be this format:

```
  <app 
    [input1]="input1$ | async" 
    [input2]="input2$ | async" 
    (inputChanged)="setInput(input)">
  </app>
```

It would be nice for us to have auto-format on and have them format this way. React has something similar for wrapping JSX attributes in the next line and aligning them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In vscode(1.27.2), press `ctrl+shift+p` and type open user settings then go to user setting file and add `"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned"` command.

Comment: it works pretty well, but is it a way to wrap only angular attribs? in square brackets only? (maybe it needs some regex but where?)

Comment: @KubaMiszcz Need to check